# Python beginner issue in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

```
      def myDict(key1, value1, key2, value2, value3, key3):
         # Write your code here
           a={key1:value1}
           print(a)
           a[key2]=value2
           print(a)
           a[key1]=value3
           print(a)
           a[key3]
           print(a)

      if __name__ == '__main__':
        key1 = 'name'
        value1 = 'rajesh'
        key2 = 'age'
        value2 = '21'
        value3 = 'vignesh'
        key3 = 'age'
        mydct = myDict(key1, value1, key2, value2, value3, key3)
        print(mydct if type(mydct) == dict else "Return a dictionary")
```

The driver function was pre-defined.
The expected output is:

```
    {'name': 'rajesh'}
    {'name': 'rajesh', 'age': '21'}
    {'name': 'vignesh', 'age': '21'}
    {'name': 'vignesh'}
```

but i'm getting as :

```
    {'name': 'rajesh'}
    {'name': 'rajesh', 'age': '21'}
    {'name': 'vignesh', 'age': '21'}
    {'name': 'vignesh'}
    Return a dictionary
```

What mistake I'm doing?

Comment: `myDict` does not return a value. Make sure you understand what `return` does, and that `print` has *nothing to do with it*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to the bottom of myDict:

```
    return a
```

Without it, `myDict` implicitly returns `None`, which is what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You missed these two lines:

```
    del a[key3]
    return a
```

Here is the complete logic:

```
def myDict(key1, value1, key2, value2, value3, key3):
        a={key1:value1}
        print(a)
        a[key2]=value2
        print(a)
        a[key1]=value3
        print(a)
        del a[key3]
        return a
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Just add ***return a*** at the last line of def function. I tried it and it got what you want. As said, if you don't put a return statement at the end of a function, you get a NoneType object, which is then it not recognize your *mydct* object as a dictionary, instead print the else statement, as you said beforehand above.

```
def myDict(key1, value1, key2, value2, value3, key3):
 # Write your code here
   a={key1:value1}
   print(a)
   a[key2]=value2
   print(a)
   a[key1]=value3
   print(a)
   a[key3]
   print(a)
   return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    key1 = 'name'
    value1 = 'rajesh'
    key2 = 'age'
    value2 = '21'
    value3 = 'vignesh'
    key3 = 'age'
    mydct = myDict(key1, value1, key2, value2, value3, key3)
    print(mydct if type(mydct) == dict else "Return a dictionary")
```

Answer (score -1):

You what to change last statement to

```
Del a[key3]
Return a
```

It will give correct output.